# Slap me when I stop working

Tags: software-recommendation

On Mac OS X I have [an app](http://blog.rinik.net/slap) that plays a sound when I enter certain  sites. I want a similar software to use on Linux. Does anybody know one?

Comment: nice Question , may be i can use this in my college to prevent students from opening these sites . thanks man .

Comment: @33833 to prevent users from opening websites, it's best to use a proxy like squid.

Comment: will you put stack exchange in those sites?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's a workaround:

```
sudo apt-get install mpg321 wmctrl

while [ 1 ]; do z=$(wmctrl -l -p | grep -i 'facebook\|miniclip'); if [ -n "$z" ]; then mpg321 myfile.mp3; fi; sleep 5; done
```

This will play myfile.mp3 if any open current window title matches "facebook" or "miniclip".

Comment: amazing this is work! but in future I want make a GUI program for this, thanks a lot.

Comment: You could probably just extend what he wrote there with this:http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/

Comment: If you have vlc media player installed you don't need mpg321, replace it with cvlc.

Comment: wow! Great!! I wish I could `thumbs up` more than one.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

There is always Rescue Time which monitors websites you visit. It doesnt slap you or anything, but it can give you a report on where you are wasting time. They even have 32 bit and 64 bit DEB files to install, plus the app in Firefox and Chrome.

Its free for basic uses, but is $6 a month if you would like to block websites, monitor how much time you spend on a doc, etc.

https://www.rescuetime.com/

DEB files and RPMs here...

https://www.rescuetime.com/setup/download

Answer (score 2):

If you use Firefox, you can try [LeechBlock](http://www.proginosko.com/leechblock.html), an extension "*designed to block those time-wasting sites that can suck the life out of your working day*". It's highly configurable and could change your life if you suffer of this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

there is an app called aplomb which was made as a part of the ubuntu app showdown a few  months ago...
i'll try n get a link to it n edit the amswer asap...if u find it,well and gud...
it lets u block sites for ur deaignatd amnt f time! :)
here is the link to the launchpad page-
https://launchpad.net/~snwh/+archive/aplomb

Comment: I think it isn't more available, on https://launchpad.net/aplomb I'm getting the message "Update: this project has been shelved indefinitely & all code has been deleted."

Comment: @ademar111190 try searching for the .deb somewhr...u may try the site http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/    u can find deb packages for most apps here...